# How to make python to choose a specific version of opencv?

Tags: python, opencv

I am using ubuntu14.04 and python2.7 and I have installed opencv3.2.0 (/usr/local) and opencv2.4.8(/usr/local/opencv/2.4.8) in my machine. The outcome of command

```
pkg-config --modversion opencv
```

is 2.4.8
while python script

```
print cv2.__version__
```

is 3.2.0.
What should I do to change it to 2.4.8?

=========================================================================

I have tried `export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/opencv/2.4.8/:$PYTHONPATH`
It seems no use

```
$ export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/opencv/2.4.8/:$PYTHONPATH
$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Oct 26 2016, 20:30:19) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
>>> print cv2.__version__
3.2.0-dev
>>>
```

**Although It shows the version is 3.2.0, it is actually using the 2.4.8, thanks for IronFarm's answer**

Comment: Install Anaconda and use virtual environments for many other python/libraries configurations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the directory for the v2.4.8 to the beginning of your PYTHONPATH environment variable before running Python.

On Linux:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/opencv/2.4.8/:$PYTHONPATH
```

Comment: I have tried this, but it seems no use.  You can see what I do above. Tanks for your answer anyway

Comment: Once inside Python you could try:
`import sys; print sys.path`

This should show you what your PYTHONPATH has been converted to inside Python.

Comment: Thanks. The path is to 2.4.8. It is actually using 2.4.8 while the verson shows 3.2.0.